# How to create component diagram from Code, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml, component-diagram

How do i create a UML component diagram in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate from Code? I cant drag anything from Architecture Explorer to the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Jetbrains Resharper for this purpose?  Resharper can generate dependency diagrams, similar to component diagrams, although not in the strict UML specification.